# How to generate colour pattern/gradient in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am setting the colour value based on range from `0 to 100 (red to green)`

As of now, a simple snippet

```
value = 5
colour = ""
if value <= 25:
   colour = "#FF0000"  # red
elif value > 25 and value <= 50:
    colour = "FF8000" # orange
elif value > 50 and value <=75:
    colour = "#FFFF00"  # yellow
elif value > 75 and value < 100:
    colour = "#53d926" # light green
```

Is it possible to set colour automatically `(gradient pattern, from red > orange > yellow > not complete green)?` as 100 indicates complete success (green).

Right now, only four colours. But based on varying percentage, it should set the colour accordingly for any `value (combination of colours from red > orange > yellow > not complete green, with respective to values)` Any smart way to handle this ?

Comment: You could use linear interpolation to get the colors in between the defined points.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry, I did not get you.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you please help me ?

Comment: Be patient.  It takes a lot longer to write a proper answer than a quick comment.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have 5 well defined points and you want a smooth gradient for values between them.

- 0: red.
- 25: orange.
- 50: yellow.
- 75: light green.
- 100: green.

You can use linear interpolation to get the colors between those defined points.  For example a value that is exactly halfway between two points would just be the average of those two colors.  The function `lerp` below provides this.

```
def all_channels2(func):
    def wrapper(channel1, channel2, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(channel1, channel2, *args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            return tuple(func(c1, c2, *args, **kwargs) for c1,c2 in zip(channel1, channel2))
    return wrapper

@all_channels2
def lerp(color1, color2, frac):
    return color1 * (1 - frac) + color2 * frac
```

And here's how you would use it:

```
def hexcolor(rgb):
    return f'#{int(rgb[0]):0>2X}{int(rgb[1]):0>2X}{int(rgb[2]):0>2X}'

if value < 25:
   colour = hexcolor(lerp((0xff, 0x00, 0x00), (0xff, 0x80, 0x00), value / 25))
elif value < 50:
    colour = hexcolor(lerp((0xFF, 0x80, 0x00), (0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00), (value - 25) / 25))
elif value < 75:
    colour = hexcolor(lerp((0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00), (0x53, 0xd9, 0x26), (value - 50) / 25))
else:
    colour = hexcolor(lerp((0x53, 0xd9, 0x26), (0x00, 0xff, 0x00), (value - 75) / 25))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark. it takes me time to understand and analyse. For time being executed this code (value = 5, int) but getting error as ValueError: Unknown format code 'X' for object of type int/float' (Python 3.9.2)

Comment: And also conditional loop can be modified as per need, otherwise above snippet encounters first 'if' statement (value < 25) always.

Comment: @stack according to the [format spec for f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) `X` should produce upper-case hex values, and it does on my system Python 3.8.  Which version of Python do you have?

Comment: @stack of course you can modify the conditionals as needed, but there's nothing wrong with what I gave here.  The example at the bottom was generated with that code, running through all the values 0 to 99.

Comment: I am using Python 3.9.2

Comment: Tried edited solution, it worked. Thank you so much Mark, will understand these concepts.

Comment: What would be the input to use these functions? Can either of you post the code you used with this to produce something, like the color bar?

Comment: @LauraMorgan it's just `for value in range(101)`.  What you do with the resulting colors is up to you.